# Spring boot RestClient post for object without request body results in bad request

Tags: rest, spring-boot, resttemplate

I am trying to make a restTemplate.postForObject() without the request body and i am getting bad request.

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
      headers.set(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer " + accessToken);
      headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
      HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);

      CurrentAccount account = client.postForObject(
          "https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/users/get_current_account", entity, CurrentAccount.class);
```

error

```
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$BadRequest: 400 Bad Request: [Error in call to API function "users/get_current_account": Bad HTTP "Content-Type" header: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".  Expecting one of "application/json", "application/json; charset=utf-8", "text/plain; charset=dropbox-cors-hack".]
```

On adding

```
 headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
```

I get an error

```
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$BadRequest: 400 Bad Request: [Error in call to API function "users/get_current_account": request body: could not decode input as JSON]
```

postman request works without body

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should also specify request body as string text *"null"*. Yes, Dropbox Api is stating that is not required to send body when issuing POST request, but it is error somewhere between how Dropbox expecting empty JSON body representation and how spring rest template is sending the empty body JSON representation, in POST request

Answer (score 1):

The error message is pretty self-explanatory. You already set `Accept` but you didn't set `Content-Type`

Add following to your headers

```java
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;

...

headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
```

Comment: On adding i get an error 
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$BadRequest: 400 Bad Request: [Error in call to API function "users/get_current_account": request body: could not decode input as JSON]

Answer (score 1):

You can use org.json.JSONObject as an empty request body:

```
restTemplate.postForEntity(
            "http://<yoururl>.com",
            new org.json.JSONObject(), <YourResponseType>.class).getBody();
```

especially if you want that the route returns something, in which case the "null" request body would not work.